# Return value from jquery model confirm or model dialog box

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

i have a javascript function like this:

**Javascript:**

```
function dailog_box(){
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            return true;   //i want to return value here
        },
            Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            return false;  //i want to return value here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Prescriptions" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_od" id="check_od"/> The prescription is correct;
    </p>
</div>
```

After calling the `dialog_box()` function i want the returned value in the variable flag and i did like this:

**Javascript**

```
 var flag = dailog_box();
 alert(flag);
```

But the result was undefined. and also the alert happens before i click any button. so what should i do to get the value after any button is clicked in the model's button

For further information you can check http://jsfiddle.net/8e388/13/
I want the returned value to be alerted.
by the way im new to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `callback`.

```
buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
            callbackSuccess();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
            Cancel: function() {
            callbackCancel();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
```

`callbackSuccess` and `callbackCancel` - is simple function

If you create helper for ConfirmDialog it will be easier to pass the callback

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have it exactly as you like. You can do this though using another way :

Check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e388/17/)

Basically I have a global variable `feedback`

```
var feedback = false;
```

And on `ok` or `cancel` of the dialog, I set the appropriate value. IMO this adds some more flexibility in your code

Comment: this is working good but i want to return the value to the var flag and i tried returning value but nothing happened and instead i also tried assigning the value of feedback to the `flag` but `false` value is assigned...how can i return that value as if it was confirm box of javascript

Comment: yes i know what you want, but as I said this is not possible (or at least I am not aware of such a method )